# Why is Supervisord configured to exec/run in the tmp folder by default?

Tags: rhel, tmp, supervisord

I've got a question regarding supervisord. After running echo_supervisord_conf, I noticed that the directory it runs in is configured as /tmp by default. Why is this the case? Is it because the /tmp folder can be written to by any of the users on the system, or does supervisord put files there because they need to be treated appropratly as temporary?

The reason I'm asking is because we've got an application running on a redhat box, and it seems like redhat automatically clears certain files out of the /tmp folder. This seems to be crashing our supervisord and our application from time to time. So I want to know why supervisord puts files in that folder and then determine if it appropriate to have it put them somewhere else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a default value that can be changed in the .conf or on the command line.
The [documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=program) itself advises to change this (at least for the socket) :

> The example configuration output by echo_supervisord_conf uses
> /tmp/supervisor.sock as the socket file. That path is an example only
> and will likely need to be changed to a location more appropriate for
> your system. Some systems periodically delete older files in /tmp. If
> the socket file is deleted, supervisorctl will be unable to connect to
> supervisord.